# how to write a script to click on combo box input box on pressing escape

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a PyQt5 combobox script written in python 3.9
One thing I like to do is, on clicking a button:

1. the input box will be cleared of inputted text
2. the input box is clicked on, so that i can start typing straight away in the input box

I am able to clear the box using self.comboBox.setCurrentText('').
However, unable to have the inputbox clicked on. As such, I have to manually click on the inputbox to start typing.

Have tried using self.comboBox.setFocus but has no effect.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: probably you need to implement a keyPressEvent handler for the parent of the QComboBox. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61722882/9705687).

Comment: Below is an extract of script. I have tested using the "escape" key sequence which can clear the text when i do so (refer to def keyPressEvent).


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.comboBox.setCurrentText('')
            self.comboBox.setFocus()  # this is to click on input box

Comment: is self.comboBox.setFocus() the right method to click on the input box?

Comment: @Ken please [edit] your post to provide the code, as comments don't support formatting. Also ensure that you're providing an *actual* [mre] (it should be *both* minimal **and** reproducible).